# What is the best way to float elements of the same class side by side?

Tags: html, css, css-float

HTML/CSS beginner here, trying to figure out the best way to do things. Ideally it would be nice to have an explanation as well as a solution.

So what I'm trying to do is placing several buttons (maybe 5-6) side by side, followed by a label

The buttons are formatted using the same CSS class. To place them side by side, I am setting float: left;

Unfortunately, this places the next element after the buttons (the label) on the same line as well, even if I set clear: both; for the label.

The problem is that float: left; governs how other elements format around the given element. This is great for the first n-1 buttons since it places the next button to the side of it. But it also places the label next to the last button.

Is there a way to fix this behavior without having to add specific CSS formatting to the last button, or provide a specific width which forces the label to be on the next line? (like maybe a different method of doing this altogether?)

This is a sample of what I'm doing now:

```
<style>
  .myButton {
    float: left;
  }
  #myLabel {
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <button class="myButton">Button 1</button>
  <button class="myButton">Button 2</button>
  <button class="myButton">Button 3</button>
  <button class="myButton">Button 4</button>
  <label id="myLabel">Output Text</label>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`label` is, by default, an `inline` element. `clear` however [only works on block-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control), which makes sense.

You would have to wrap the buttons in a separate element, and/or apply `display:block` to the label.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to float your buttons; they will naturally flow next to each other the same as text (kinda). If you want to put the label on its own line, you have a couple options:

1. Put a line break (`<br />`) in the html between the last button and the label
2. Make your label `display: block;` in the CSS, which will ensure that it's the only thing on its line (after the floats are gone)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxs6b1fj/3/). I basically wrapped the buttons in a `<div id="buttons">` and assigned the following styles to that `<div>`.

```
#buttons {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```